# How can I read Face ID logs in my iPhone?

Tags: logs, face-id

I want to see what is stored in my iPhone when I use Face ID technology to log in.

Is there any way to retrieve a log related to this topic from my iPhone?

Comment: This question is not at all clear. You mean other than a 3D digital representation of your face stored in a secure enclave so no-one, not even Apple, can get into it? And please confirm whether you mean FaceTime, as your title, or Face ID, as the body.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected title. I meant face Id, as explained in question and tags. I don't care about the digital representation of my face, I just want to know how to get log data out of an iPhone and if that log data contains something like: "10-10-2021 22:34 logged in using face Id" (just an example, clearly)

Comment: Getting any kind of data out of an iPhone is likely to require purchase of iMazing or similar, plus some knowledge of sql. It's *way* beyond my expertise, so I'll leave this for those who know better than me. Wish you luck :)

Comment: I’ll provide a general log answer. It’s not at all clear what database or logs are relevant since these are all private and undocumented API. Whether Apple generates or retains security related logs is not at all given - especially if ratting on users could be exploited for no good benefit to the owner of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides access to console logs in several ways.

1. Xcode and Finder can pair devices and then use the native Mac console app
2. You can collect diagnostic logs or view them on iOS.
3. Command line tools like `log` and the cli for Apple Configurator may be of assistance.

Some references:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs
- https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-2/view-log-messages-and-activity-cad35876148/mac
- https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-2/use-the-command-line-tool-cad856a8ea58/mac

I’ve only used these for other cases, but if Apple logs security events, you might be in luck.

Comment: I deeply thank you for your precious and kind help.
The fact that apple does not document this is a bit... 
Terrifying.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow the terror here, but I’m glad I could be of help. The security white papers Apple publishes are quite detailed. https://www.apple.com/ca/business-docs/FaceID_Security_Guide.pdf and https://support.apple.com/guide/security/welcome/web